# MySQL query to group by and then take difference based on criteria instead of sum

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Here is my table

```
Type  Amount  Year  Month
P     10      2016  1
P     15      2016  2
T     5       2016  1
T     20      2016  3
```

There will only be one month-year combination for P and T. In other words, there cannot be two rows with P having the same Year and Month combination.

Here's what I'd like to do

Get the difference in amount (amount in P row minus amount in T row) where month and year are the same. If there is no corresponding P or T row, then assume amount is 0. So the output would be

```
Amount  Year  Month
5       2016  1 
15      2016  2
-20     2016  3
```

What is the simplest way of doing this (by simple, I mean least amount of code repetition). One way I can think of is to first get the P and T rows into two separate derived tables (using select statements), then do a left join union with a right join, but this involves a lot of code repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT `Year`, `Month`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN `Type` = 'P' THEN `Amount` ELSE -`Amount` END) AS Amount
FROM tab
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`;
```

Output:

```
╔══════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ Year ║ Month ║ Amount ║
╠══════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ 2016 ║     1 ║      5 ║
║ 2016 ║     2 ║     15 ║
║ 2016 ║     3 ║    -20 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/442593)**</kbd>

Using [`IF function`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT `Year`, `Month`,
        SUM(IF(`Type` = 'P', `Amount`, -`Amount`)) AS Amount
FROM tab
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`;
```

---

Another way is to use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT `Year`, `Month`, SUM(`Amount`) AS Amount
FROM (SELECT `Year`, `Month`, `Amount`
      FROM tab
      WHERE `Type` = 'P'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT `Year`, `Month`, -`Amount`
      FROM tab
      WHERE `Type` = 'T') AS sub
GROUP BY `Year`, `Month`;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/442598)**</kbd>